# Creating SQL Server 2008 Add-Ons: current equivalent of sqlwb.exe

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, add-in, add-on

I'm trying to create a simple Add-On for SQL Server 2008; it is simply going to pass a parameter from SQL 2008 to a console application.

Although Add-Ons are not specifically supported, according to these articles ([1](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/jonsayce/archive/2008/01/15/building-a-sql-server-management-studio-addin.aspx), [2](http://jcooney.net/archive/2007/11/26/55358.aspx)), it is possible in 2005 and I'm assuming also in 2008. However, I've fallen almost at the first hurdle; I can't seem to find SQLWB.EXE (SQL WorkBench) in the expected place. I'm assuming that this file has been replaced in 2008, but I can't seem to pin down the equivalent version.

Has anyone any experience in general in developing 2008 Add-ons? Any good resources?

And can anyone indicate the 2008 replacement for SQLWB.EXE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql Server Management Studio:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. SSMS existed in SQL 2005 as well. SQLWB had a different purpose.

Comment: I can't remember why, but I was under the same impression. But checking a SQL 2005 instance, I can't find SSMS.EXE. Further more, the following link seems to indicate that SQLWB *is* SSMS in 2005 - http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/05/sql-server-2005-open-ssms-from-command-prompt-sqlwbexe-example/. I think David may well be right, which is slightly annoying because it means that I've been conducting a 'wild goose chase'!

Comment: @ichiban it does. ssms now does what sqlwb did before. you can use parameters with ssms